# Ubuntu. Что указать в ярлыке, чтобы программа запустилась в одной консоли, минуя gnome-terminal?

Tags: ubuntu

Я пытаюсь настроить ярлык программы Ranger, который будет запускать её через терминал "rxvt-unicode" (urxvt), и это выходит, но сначала запускается консоль gnome (gnome-terminal вроде), и через неё уже включается urxvt с Ranger внутри. (см. [скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6BJV.png))

Всё работает, но мне хотелось бы, чтобы первая консоль закрывалась после запуска второй ([вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA3zw.png)). Первую консоль можно закрыть вручную, нажав кнопку крестик, но в ярлыке у меня это описать не получается. Сейчас ярлык (ranger.desktop) выглядит так:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ranger
Comment=Launches the ranger file manager
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Exec=urxvt -e ranger
Categories=ConsoleOnly;System;FileTools;FileManager
MimeType=inode/directory;
Keywords=File;Manager;Browser;Explorer;Launcher;Vi;Vim;Python
```

([скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0HqE.png)).

Если закрыть rxvt, то и первая консоль мгновенно закроется. Вместо rxvt пробовал запускать терминал sakura, но с ней та же проблема. Точнее, проблема в ярлыке. Я просто не понимаю, как запустить ranger сразу в rxvt, минуя gnome-terminal.

Команды в exec вроде `nohup ... && exit` почему-то не помогают. Первая консоль не хочет закрываться по команде из exec ярлыка. Но при этом, как я и говорил, gnome-terminal можно закрыть, нажав курсором на кнопку "закрыть" (крестик).

Нужно заметить, что ranger - консольная программа, и её нужно запускать в каком-нибудь терминале.

Comment: так а чего сразу в gnome-terminal не запустить ? оно и выглядеть будет поприличнее.

Comment: @Zt. Это вообще исключено, потому что не будет работать модуль на превью картинок. https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Image-Previews#with-w3mimgdisplay. Если есть хоть какие-то советы и поддержка по другим консолям, то о гномском терминале тут ни слова.(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй Terminal=false,
нет смысла указывать Terminal=true, если urxvt уже сам по себе терминал.

Comment: Спасибо. Чувствую себя шизиком. Представляете, я уже написал скрипт для запуска: '
    urxvt -e ranger $1 &
    sleep 1
    killall gnome-terminal-server
'